# How to view a info file in Browser?

Tags: browser, info

I am wondering if there are any info viewers for the browser ? 
Info is a good structured document and has a good potential for replacing browser man pages Does anyone have any idea ? 
Info files are usually viewer in info/emacs/tkman etc on Unix system but they generally lack font changing flexibility .

Comment: Use Firefox, it can open nfo files.

Comment: I am on Firefox - How to open them though ? I hope nfo is same info ?